# Dynamically size cell based on content iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell shown in attachment:

[image]

I am using a UIWebView to display tweet text. Some of the tweets are short and I want to resize the web view, move up the Time Since, and then finally resize the cell. I know how to resize the web view, but don't know how to figure out how to move the time since and resize the cell.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = nil;

    if (self.tweetsSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == REPORTERS_SELECTED_INDEX)
    {
        fetchedResultsController = self.reportersFetchedResultsController;

    }
    else if (self.tweetsSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == PLAYERS_SELECTED_INDEX)
    {
        fetchedResultsController = self.playersFetchedResultsController;
    }

    Tweet *tweet = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Calcaulate height of box, instead of return a fixed number 
    return 170;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to resize the web view

Don't. Use autosizing to stretch the UIWebView with height of the cell.

> how to move the time since

Don't. Use autosizing to pin Time Since to the bottom of the cell.

> resize the cell

Use `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

---

**Update**

The way I did this before is to set a known size for the flexible view (for you the web view) in the prototype cell and set a known size for the prototype cell. In this case we'll say the web view is kPrototypeViewHeight and the prototype is kPrototypeCellHeight.

In the table view controller:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIWebView *webView = … // Whatever you need to do to get the web view
    CGFloat webViewHeight = webView.frame.size.height;
    return kPrototypeCellHeight - kPrototypeViewHeight + webViewHeight;
}
```

Note: This will be done before `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called. So you need to know your size before you have to draw yourself.

Note 2: Because you are changing the size of webView yourself, you will not want it autosized.

Note 3: You will be redering each web view in your table to calculate your height. My guess is scrolling will be very slow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to I know how tall to make the row as the content inside of the web view determines the size of the cell?

Comment: See new comment. I like the autosize approach, I just need to figure out how to find how tall the text is.

Comment: @ChrisMuench That seems to be difficult for an HTML view. If you had simple text you could use one of the `-sizeWithFont:` family of methods. If you really need this to work as HTML, you might want to look at [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).